# ANGULAR: Not able to pass string containing {{}} in directive scope using @ after upgrading to angular version to 1.2.3

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm passing  `"/foo/bar/{{value}}"` as a string using @ to the directive so I can use the interpolate method to construct hrefs for a dropdown. I think angular is looking for value when compiling instead of passing the whole thing as a string. This was working fine in the angular v1.2.0.

The directive code goes like,

```
return {
templateUrl: '/views/directives/directive-name.html',
restrict: 'E',
replace: true,
scope: {
  title: '@',
  optHref: '@'
},
link:  link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
  var hrefFormatter;


  hrefFormatter = $interpolate(attrs.optHref);

  scope.getHref = function(value, label) {
    return hrefFormatter({ value: value, label: label });
  }; 
}
```

Invoked like,

`<directive-name
  title ="name"
  opt-href="/foo/bar/{{value}}" <
</directive-name>`

Appreciate any pointers on what might have changed in angular to cause this or other pointers.

Comment: What's actually happening with the above code? Can you setup a plnkr that shows it? One thing that springs to mind is that "link" might be too late to have access to the non-interpolated function with {{value}} still intact. You might have to do something during the "compile" phase, or a controller for the directive.

Comment: The test was failing and only "/foo/bar/" was passed in, whereas I needed "/foo/bar/{{value}}" so I could use the $interpolate in the link function to replace the value.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
opt-href="/foo/bar/{{value}}"
```

Try this:

```
opt-href="'/foo/bar/{{value}}'"
```

Mind the additional `'`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Michal! Used a controller function before the link to preserve the `attrs.optHref` in the scope. Something like,

```
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        $scope.optHref = $attrs.optHref;
     }
```

In the controller function the `{{value}}` was already interpolated in scope but existed in attrs. But in the link fn `{{value}}` was interpolated in attrs as well- so preserved it in scope and used `scope.optHref`in the link fn.